# Looping cv.glmnet and get the 'best' coefficients

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet, coefficients

As noted in the help of cv.glmnet, "the results of cv.glmnet are random, since the folds are selected at random. Users can reduce this randomness by running cv.glmnet many times, and averaging the error curves.".

If I make a loop doing n-times cv.glmnet, how can I extract the 'best' coefficients? I usually take the coefficients using this command:

```
coe<- coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
```

If I use the mean of all the "lambda.min" then I don't know how to choose the right cvfit out of the many I generated. Do I have to use the mean of cvfit$cvm or MSE or other things?

Thanks

Comment: Or you could increase the number of folds approacing LOOCV, that way you do not have to do repeated CV.

Answer (score 1):

when you do `coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")`, you are taking the lambda that is 1 standard error from the best lambda, see [this discusssion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/138569/why-is-lambda-within-one-standard-error-from-the-minimum-is-a-recommended-valu) So you can average the MSEs across different cv runs

```
library(glmnet)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
X = as.matrix(BostonHousing[,-c(4,14)])
Y = BostonHousing[,14]
nfolds = 5
nreps = 10

res = lapply(1:nreps,function(i){
fit = cv.glmnet(x=X,y=Y,nfolds=nfolds)
data.frame(MSE_mean=fit$cvm,lambda=fit$lambda,se=fit$cvsd)
})
res = do.call(rbind,res)
```

We can summarize the results, the standard deviation is approximated by just taking the mean, but if you wanna be precise, might have to look into the [formula for pooled standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance):

```
library(dplyr)

summarized_res = res %>% 
group_by(lambda) %>% 
summarise(MSE=mean(MSE_mean),se=mean(se)) %>%
arrange(desc(lambda))

idx = which.min(summarized_res$MSE)
lambda.min = summarized_res$lambda[idx]
lambda.min
[1] 0.019303

index_1se = with(summarized_res,which(MSE < MSE[idx]+se[idx])[1])
lambda_1se = summarized_res$lambda[index_1se]
lambda_1se
[1] 0.3145908
```

We can plot this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res,aes(x=log(lambda),y=MSE_mean)) + stat_summary(fun=mean,size=2,geom="point") + 
geom_vline(xintercept=c(lambda.min,lambda_1se))
```

[image]